# Visualize dataflow in reporting stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, flowchart

I have a SP that uses many tabels and produces a table as output. Is there a way to map the data flow in an automatic way? E.g. many intermediary tables are created which combine to create new tables...

I also would like to check the data types in an efficient way to see e.g. if they are compatible in joins etc.

Or maybe something like a ER diagram but when there is no PK-FK relationship between the tables.

So basically I would like to create some form of diagram to give me an overview of a long stored procedure.

Thanks

Comment: Well, good luck. And no, SQL Server (or rather Management Studio) has nothing like that built in, and recommendations for third-party tools are off-topic on SO. You could certainly attempt to write software that does something like this, for example using `TSqlParser`, but it would not be an afternoon project.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want some sort of execution plan. SentryOne have some good products for that.

Comment: @sTTu, funny I was just thinking the same.